# Fastest way to count from a subquery

Tags: sql

I have the following query to return a list of current employees and the number of 'corrections' they have. This is working correctly but is very slow.

I was previously not using a subquery, instead opting for a count (from...) as an aggregate subselect but I have read that a subquery should be much faster. Changing to the code to the below did improve performance but not anywhere near what I was expecting.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
tblStaff.StaffID, CorrectionsOut.Count AS CorrectionsAssigned

FROM tblStaff 

LEFT JOIN tblMeetings ON tblMeetings.StaffID = tblStaff.StaffID
JOIN tblTasks ON tblTasks.TaskID = tblMeetings.TaskID

--Get Corrections Issued
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT tblMeetings.TaskID) AS Count, tblMeetings.StaffID    
    FROM tblRegister    
    JOIN tblMeetings ON tblRegister.MeetingID = tblMeetings.MeetingID   
    WHERE tblRegister.FDescription IS NOT NULL 
        AND tblRegister.CorrectionOutDate IS NULL        
    GROUP BY tblMeetings.StaffID 
) AS CorrectionsOut ON CorrectionsOut.StaffID = tblStaff.StaffID 


WHERE tblStaff.CurrentEmployee = 1
```

I need an open vendor solution as we are transitioning from SQL Server to Postgres. Note this is a simplified example of the query where there are quite few counts. My current query time without the counts is less than half a second, but with the counts, is approx 20 seconds, if it runs at all without locking or otherwise failing.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help, as would an explanation of what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the joins that you are not using which probably makes the `SELECT DISTINCT` unnecessary as well:

```
SELECT s.StaffID, co.Count AS CorrectionsAssigned
FROM tblStaff s LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT m.TaskID) AS Count, m.StaffID    
      FROM tblRegister r
           tblMeetings m
           ON r.MeetingID = m.MeetingID   
      WHERE r.FDescription IS NOT NULL AND
            r.CorrectionOutDate IS NULL        
      GROUP BY m.StaffID 
     ) co
     ON co.StaffID = s.StaffID
WHERE s.CurrentEmployee = 1;
```

Getting rid of the `SELECT DISTINCT` and the duplicate rows added by the tasks should help performance.

For additional benefit, you would want to be sure you have indexes on the `JOIN` keys, and perhaps on the filtering criteria.